# Retrieve cdn Subdomain folder files

Tags: php, subdomain

I am not able to retrieve subdomain folder files.

I am storing some musics and images in cdn subdomain.I am able to retrieve that files using file names like ..

http://cdn.domain.com/30/1.png. But I am not able to retrieve folder file..

```
    <?php
    define('CDN', 'http://cdn.domain.com/');
    ?>

  <select class="form-control select" data-live-search="true"  name="demomedia">
 <option value="">Select One Demo File</option> 
 $id=30;
 <?php
    echo $dir11 = CDN.$id.'/';
    // Sort in ascending order - this is default
    echo $a = scandir($dir11);
    $files = array_diff($a, array('.', '..'));
    foreach($files as $jesfile)
    {
            echo "<option value='".$jesfile."'>".$jesfile."</option>";
            $sss='';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

when I echo this it shows correct path http://cdn.domain.com/30/

And I am able retrieve using this code in web folders like

```
$dir11 = '../demo/'.$id.'/';
```

Please help me how do I retrieve subdomain folder files..

Comment: You are trying to run `scandir` on a URL, which will not work. Perhaps if your URL will show a directory listing you can parse that.